# Proxy Server that supports Javascript Injection

Tags: java, javascript, python, proxy

I'm current working in Python and have started messing around with Proxy servers. I have a small application written using spynner. What I'd like to do is find some form of proxy software or python proxy server library that allows me to inject a javascript code in to every page that passes through the server.

Has anyone heard of something like this? I've been googling around for hours but the best I could find was the selenium server which doesn't seem to work correctly for what I want.

Any help is apprecieated, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a [forward proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Forward_proxies) to sit between a client (Web Browser) and the internet, or do you need a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to sit in front of a particular server

Comment: A forward proxy sounds like the best option! Just something to be inbetween the internet and the browswer, but will inject a piece of javascript as pages are received. I'm looking for the script to inject at the beginning of the page, rather then the end.